# How do I protect the power supply from a short circuit inside a device?

Tags: fuses, adapter, security

I'm working on an electronics project which would be powered by a 12V power adapter.

I'm worried that in a case of a short circuit inside the device I'm making, the adapter could catch fire. Every adapter I have at home has no indicators about any protection against short circuits (nor even whether they are regulated or not), and no company name or ID which would allow to check its specs.

Example of a commonly used no-name adapter:

[image]

Let's say the adapter is a 12V, 1A adapter (and the device uses maximum 350 mA). Would it be enough to put a 12-32V, 1A fuse between the adapter and the device, in order to be sure that whatever happens *inside* the device won't cause the adapter to catch fire?

Comment: If the device uses 350mA, use a 400mA or 500mA fuse. These *might* blow fast enough at 1A, and will blow if the adapter can supply much more than 1A for long enough (up to a few seconds)

Comment: Use an adapter with a suitable rating (for safety, there's  many international agencies that test-and-certify).   Since a DC cord can short, there'salready protection inside any such adapter against fire hazard.

Comment: Approved adapters have OCP and OTP, random Chinese ones may or may not. That's not on you, and there's nothing really you can do on the device end to prevent a faulty supply from catching fire.

Comment: Fuses are only suitable for protecting robust things like wiring. The difference between 'must carry' and 'must break' currents is large, and can be 10:1 ratio by the time you get down to opening fast enough to protect semiconductors. Short a power supply, under controlled and safe conditions, and see what it does.

Comment: @Neil_UK luckily any problem is quite likely to be a complete short circuit, not a 3:1 overcurrent event...

Comment: The problem with fusing the output of a power supply is that the supply may not have the current output to be able to blow the fuse quickly or at all. This was a mistake Hewlett Packard made in their 3325 waveform generator. The 5 V rail was 'protected' by a crowbar, which when triggered, the power supply was unable to blow the fuse, so sat and cooked, filled the lab with smoke, and wrote off the instrument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple way to address this is to use a *polyfuse* inside your device. These work by detecting an overcurrent condition, then 'tripping' to limit the current to a lower value until the power is removed, at which point it self-resets. They're sometimes called 'PTC' or 'positive-temperature-coefficient' fuses.

More here: https://www.littelfuse.com/products/polyswitch-resettable-pptcs.aspx

If you're concerned about other faults like overvoltage or reverse voltage, there's more advanced solutions available. You might even consider thermal sensing with shutdown if there's a possibility your device might not get enough ventilation.

Comment: Isn't a polyfuse slow to react? From what I remember, they trip by overheating, and this process can be quite slow compared to ordinary glass fuses, which, I would imagine, could let the power adapter to catch fire before the polyfuse trips. Am I wrong?

Comment: They're not that slow - they'll interrupt well before something downstream heats up to the point of catching fire. Bear in mind also that traditional fuses work the very same way: by heating, so there could be transients that wouldn't cause even a glass fuse to blow.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko You can find different models of fuse that have different "trip" times. Many applications specifically require fast- or slow-blowing fuses, so there are a wide variety available.

Answer (score 6):

Put a fuse inside the device you are designing.

You know the power and the voltage and current so select a suitable fuse with sufficient headroom and fast or slow blow as applicable.

Comment: Bonus: use one of those fuses that unscrews from the rear panel or is integrated into the IEC cutout.

Answer (score 2):

The nature of A/C adapters is that when you try to draw more power from them than they are rated for, the voltage drops as the current increases, and the total number of Watts doesn't increase, and no more heat is generated.  This is because the transformer saturates.  This is why you don't see in-line fuses on power adapters.

If the adapter is not UL rated, you can short the plus and minus to confirm nothing catches fire.  If it melts the wiring (it shouldn't), you should consider a 1A slow-blow fuse.  Bear in mind that fuses can eventually fail if you operate near their limit.

Also, it's not uncommon for a 350 mA device to draw a few amps at bootup due to inrush current.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the transformer does not saturate under increased load. The load current reduces the flux in the core, it doesn't increase it.

Comment: Far more often the inductor would go into discontinuous conduction mode well before the transformer sags, likely kicking on OCP.

Comment: Wouldn't a saturated transformer behave like a short circuit on the mains side?